# How do you know what status code to test for?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am learning Django from a book which doesn't really explain the status codes very well when testing, i understand that a successful/accepted request gives a status code of 200, but i cant get my head around how you would know which one to expect when testing? For example:

```
def test_post_update_view(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post_edit', args='1'), {
            'title': 'Updated title',
            'body': 'Updated text',
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)


    def test_post_delete_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('post_delete', args='1'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

i am following along making a blog website from the book testing the different views, but when testing the UpdateView test we checked for a 302 but on the DeleteView we checked for a 200, why do we not expect a 302 with the DeleteView?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302. `302` is status code for redirection (could also be `301`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find all sorts of http status codes in the wild. Also 
 Typically, you would expect 2xx codes for successful CRUD operations.

Django rest framework uses these http codes for rest endpoints.

```
create: 201
update: 200
delete: 204
```

But if you are performing these operations by posting a html form, it's common practice to always return a redirect. This is to prevent users from unintentionally submitting the same payload several times by pressing "reload" on a web page containing a submit form. [This pattern has its own StackOverflow tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get)

For a delete view it might not be a big deal, since delete should be an idempotent operation. If you use django's builtin `django.views.generic.DeleteView` it should return a redirect on a successful deletion. [ccbv source](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/DeletionMixin/#delete)

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
    success URL.
    """
    self.object = self.get_object()
    success_url = self.get_success_url()
    self.object.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

So to figure out which status code to expect in your test, you have to look at the view you are testing.

Also make sure you are using the proper http method in you request. Both `delete` and `post` should work the same with the generic views.

```
  response = self.client.delete(reverse('post_delete', args='1'))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however i am using the built in DeleteView but it returns a 200 not a 302 which is what i cant get my head around as on delete it uses the `success_url = reverse_lazy('home')` which takes it back to the homepage, is this not a redirect?

Comment: I noticed you use the `client.get` method. You should use delete or post.

Comment: yea just tried it with the delete method and it did give a 302 status code, little confusing why it accepts get then

Comment: i guess then it means that it successfully redirected you to a page that gives a 200 status code, after the delete?

Comment: I think get is for rendering a delete form initially, and a "delete successful" page after deletion and redirection.